# How to get Icon for a specific format on mac

Tags: java, macos

I'n my application I need to add icons of files next to `Jlabel`s and so on. By `FileSystemView` it is easy to make a temporary `file` with a format and it gives the corresponding icon. But it does not work on `Mac`. Doesn't `FileSystemView` really work on `Mac` or it is just my code.

If `FileSystemView` is only for `Windows`, is there any similar way for mac to get native icons of mac?

Thanks

Comment: 'Is it just my code'. Can you provide the code you are using? Do you wish to get the 'preview' icon, or the icon associated with an application?

Comment: Further, can you explain what you mean by 'does not work'?